# How to click on a link and call function on the page that link go to as the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, function

- index.html - has menus `category1`, `category2`, `category3`
- product.html - has function `changeIframe([category1 | category2 | category3]);`

When I click a menu on "index.html" page, a link will bring me to "product.html" page then call function `changeIframe(var)` immediately. The `changeIframe(var)` function will compare `$var` (value of `var` is followed by the name of menu that I clicked) and then change content in this page. How can I do something like this?

Comment: I think you'll need to use php or some other programming language otherwise you might have to explode the url in js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an Idea, pass the category as Url Hash.

index.html:

```
<a href="product.html#category1">Category 1</a>
<a href="product.html#category2">Category 2</a>
<a href="product.html#category3">Category 3</a>
```

product.html

```
var category = (location.hash).replace('#','');
changeIframe(category); //call function
```

If only you do need it using javascript. It'll be more easier if you using server-side script.

Comment: it's such a good idea. you mean run function onload and check condition, huh?

Answer (score 1):

Add the categories as hashtag on your link and read that out.

```
<a href="product.html#category1">menu link</a>
```

In your product page

```
window.onload = function(){

    var category = (window.location.hash).replace("#",'');;
    alert(category);
    // changeIframe(category)

}
```

And remove the "#" like @Charlie shows.

Answer (score 1):

index.html

```
<a href="product.html#category1">category 1</a>
<a href="product.html#category2">category 2</a>
<a href="product.html#category3">category 3</a>
```

product.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var item =  toLowerCase((document.location.hash)).replace('#','');
    if(/category[1-3]/i.test(item)){
        changeIframe(item);
    }else{
        changeIframe(defaultitem);
    }
});
```

if you are using php

index.html

```
<a href="product.html?item=category1">category 1</a>
<a href="product.html?item=category2">category 2</a>
<a href="product.html?item=category3">category 3</a>
```

product.html

```
<script>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['item']) && preg_match("/category[1-3]/", $_GET['item'])){
    echo "changeIframe(" . $_GET['item'] .");";
}else{
    echo "changeIframe(defaultitem);";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On index.phtml page when you Click  link pass menu name as a query string and when you reach the product.phtml call the changeiframe(var) on $(document).ready function

Answer (score 0):

One way of going about it using using PHP (if you have a server that supports it).

If you end up getting PHP setup, here is one option:

index.php:

```
<a href="product.php?cat=1">Category 1</a>
<a href="product.php?cat=1">Category 2</a>
<a href="product.php?cat=1">Category 3</a>
```

then use this code with your Javascript in product.php to get the category passed:

```
changeIframe(<?php $_GET['cat'] ?>)
```

Comment: If you use PHP then you fetch the variable with `$_GET['cat']` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

pass link as query string `product.html?category=1` and can use this code in that page

```
  function getUrlVars()
    {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;

    }



    $(document).ready(function() {   

   var id = getUrlVars()["category"];
    changeIframe(var);
    });
```